# nested Linq Query Returned an error at run time(Unable to create a constant value of type Anonymous type)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

here you can find the whole Exception https://pastebin.com/gfHdTUKd

```
                var rangeReports = dbCon.RangeReports.Where(x => x.PatientRegistrationId == pidReg)
                    .Select(x => new { x.TestID, x.Value, x.TestDate })
                    .OrderBy(x => x.TestDate).Distinct().ToList();


                var ReportsData = dbCon.Tests
                        .Select(t => new 
                        {
                            ID = t.ID,
                            Name = t.Name,
                            reports = rangeReports.Where(rr => rr.TestID == t.ID)
                             .Select(rr => new { TestDate = rr.TestDate, Value = rr.Value }).ToList()
                        }).ToList();
```

**If i remove below Line of Code from an above query It works fine, couldn't find exact issue.**

```
reports = rangeReports.Where(rr => rr.TestID == t.ID)
                                 .Select(rr => new { TestDate = rr.TestDate, Value = rr.Value }).ToList()
```

your help will be highly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Remove the last `.ToList()` from `var rangeReports = ...`, thus keeping it query rather than in-memory collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If materialize second query first, this should fix the issue:

```
            var ReportsData = dbCon.Tests
                    .Select(t => new 
                    {
                        ID = t.ID,
                        Name = t.Name
                    })
                    .ToList() //Materialize the query first
                    .Select(t => new 
                    {
                        ID = t.ID,
                        Name = t.Name,
                        reports = rangeReports.Where(rr => rr.TestID == t.ID)
                         .Select(rr => new { TestDate = rr.TestDate, Value = rr.Value }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```